# Why did I receive badge notification which I have already earned?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, notifications

Yesterday I received notification 2 times on main site (as well as for Stack Overflow) that I have earned "Marshal" badge, which I have already earned back in [November 2015](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/208/marshal?userid=87130).

See the below screenshot for more understanding about notification:
[image]

Is this any kind of bug? Why did I receive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there was a bug with Marshal and Excavator badges, across the network. It has been fixed by now: the badges are back to normal, the inbox notifications remaining as the only reminder of the incident. For details, see [Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280023)